# Perl: regex won't work without parentheses

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a simple script in Perl to check string for different wordforms (in english and russian) of a nickname. I would use the next regex: `/(gunn?er|gunn?|ганн?еру?|ганн?у?)/i` - which is valid, according to [regex101.com test](https://www.regex101.com/r/yC3yB2/2) and Notepad++. However, on my computer in Perl this regex doesn't work unless I put additional parentheses to `?` and `|`: `/((gun(n)?er)|(gun(n)?)|(ган(н)?ер(у)?)|(ган(н)?(у)?)/i`. My friend, whom I've asked of this, couldn't reproduce this behavior. Is it some kind of setting of script or Perl interpreter itself that I should change?

**Edit:** As requested, the code of my tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $GUN = "gunner";
my $HZ = "!!!";

sub GetNickFromMsg
{
    my ($msg) = @_;
    if ( $msg =~ /(gunn?er|gunn?|ганн?еру?|ганн?у?)/i )
    {
        return $GUN
    }
    return $HZ;
}

my @nicks = ("Gunner", "guner", "ганнер", "ганеру", "гану");
foreach $n (@nicks)
{
    my $res = GetNickFromMsg($n);
    print "$n -> $res\n");
}
```

The output I get:

```
Gunner -> !!!
guner -> !!!
ганнер -> !!!
ганеру -> !!!
гану -> !!!
```

If I change the regex to the second version, with parentheses everywhere, the output for every wordform is "-> gunner" as it should be. I've tried to add `use feature 'unicode_strings'` to the beginning of the script and use `ui` instead of `i` modifier as Casimir supposed, but it didn't help.

I launch the script on Linux server, `Linux version 4.3.0-1-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 5.3.1 20160101 (Debian 5.3.1-5) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5 (2016-01-04)` with Perl version 5.22.1

Comment: Writing `/(gunn?er|gunn?|ганн?еру?|ганн?у?)/i` in Perl is perfectly valid, your problem comes from elsewhere. You should show your code. Since you use unicode characters, did you start your code with `use feature 'unicode_strings'` or use the u modifier?

Comment: I've  never seen the error `doesn't work`. I don't suppose you can provide an actual example?

Comment: The `use feature 'unicode_strings'` only exists from Perl 5.12.

Comment: You say you program contains `н`, but that character can't possibly exist in a Perl program without `use utf8;`. The default encoding is effectively iso-8859-1, and that character doesn't exist in iso-8859-1.

Comment: @ikegami but on my virtual machine and on my friend's computer it works fine without `use utf8`. All three systems have same versions of Perl and same locales, `ru_RU.UTF-8`. Besides, applying simple regexes like `gunner|ганнер` worked just fine - that's mainly what triggered the question and why I didn't think it was related to Unicode settings.

Comment: Again, you source code couldn't possibly have contained `gunner|ганнер` without `use utf8;`. (Your locale is completely irrelevant.) It actually contains `gunner|Ð³Ð°Ð½Ð½ÐµÑ�`. As for it working fine, I'll grant you that it's possible for bugs in this area to cancel out (e.g. it'll work if you also had `Ð³Ð°Ð½Ð½ÐµÑ�` and not `ганнер` for input), but that doesn't mean it's fine. Your very question proves that things aren't fine as they are; you simply got lucky with the example in your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `use utf8` at the top of your program to specify that your program code uses UTF-8-encoded characters

You will also need to set STDOUT to handle UTF-8 encoding, otherwise you will get `Wide character in print` warnings

Here's an edited version of your program that works correctly and provides the behaviour that you expected

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /;

my $GUN = 'gunner';
my $HZ  = '!!!';

sub GetNickFromMsg {
    my ($msg) = @_;

    if ( $msg =~ /(gunn?er|gunn?|ганн?еру?|ганн?у?)/i ) {
        return $GUN;
    }

    return $HZ;
}

my @nicks = qw/ Gunner guner ганнер ганеру гану /;

foreach my $n (@nicks) {
    my $res = GetNickFromMsg($n);
    print "$n -> $res\n";
}
```

#### output

```
Gunner -> gunner
guner -> gunner
ганнер -> gunner
ганеру -> gunner
гану -> gunner
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you much! Just to clarify: does it mean that in my case each Unicode character was treated as two separate ones, so to speak, the `н?` would become `\0xD0\0xBD?` with `?` applied only to the second byte?